# Upgrading to Log4J2 facing exception. [Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager]

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, log4j2

I am trying to upgrade a project to use log4J2 instead of Log4J1. It is maven project which is using some other projects as well in its dependency. Before any dependency, I have following in POM file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
<version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

I have no compile time error, but when i try to execute, I keep getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'userService' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Accept/dev/apache-t
omcat-6.0.29/lib/accept-planner-lib.jar!/com/accept/modules/resources/impl/UserS
erviceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.N
oClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
```

Complete stack trace : http://pastebin.com/uWXaTSZ0

Any guidance, pointers are really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download **jar** containing **org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager** and then set your **classpath**.
[link to download log4j 2 jar](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html)
or try this
[link to download jar](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html)

download required jar from these two link

Comment: Would not it happen automatically, considering dependency section in pom.xml? Even if i download the jar, i have to locally install it in maven repository. I am sorry, can you please elaborate

Comment: Have you download the jar?

Comment: Reason may be your existing jar doesn't contain required class download latest version of jar file

Comment: No, I have not downloaded it. I am not sure why i should download it, when its there in pom.xml. Also I have checked the LogManager.class exists in org.apache.logging.log4j

Comment: classnotfoundexception occurs when the required class is not there or if class is there then the required method is not present in that class

Comment: I am feeling you. Let me try to add Log4J manually and see if it resolve the defect.

Comment: Putting the log4J2xx.jar in class path did remove the error. What I need to debug is why application is not looking at local repo, when in run mode.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and have found the problem and solved it. The reason is that scope=test which is inherited from parent pom is the cause. Solution: set scope=compile